# parse this xml file in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dsml

How to parse this xml file in java to read all the attributes of this XML file in java?

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?
<dsml:batchRequest xmlns:dsml="urn:oasis:names:tc:DSML:2:0:core"                  
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-   instance">


    <dsml:addRequest  dn="cn=stifford,ou=Users,o=data">

  <attr name="objectclass"><value>top</value></attr>
  <attr name="objectclass"><value>person</value></attr>
  <attr name="objectclass"><value>organizationalPerson</value></attr>
  <attr name="objectclass"><value>inetorgperson</value></attr>
  <attr name="UID"><value>kevin985</value></attr>
  <attr name="sn"><value>kevin</value></attr>
  <attr name="givenName"><value>stifford</value></attr>
   <attr name="telephoneNumber"><value>9852898994</value></attr>
  <attr name="mail"><value>sample@bsample.com</value></attr>
```

Comment: Did you search anything?

Comment: just check this link http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-jdom-example/

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MarshalException,
ValidationException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException,
IOException {

    File fXmlFile = new File(
            "/home/Parsing/src/com/parsing/test.xml");
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

    Node node = doc.getDocumentElement().getParentNode();

    System.out.println(doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

    NodeList itemList = node.getChildNodes();
    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.getLength(); i++) {

        Node nNode = itemList.item(i);

        System.out.println("Current Element : " + nNode.getNodeName());

        getChildNode(nNode.getChildNodes());

    }
}

private static void getChildNode(NodeList childNodes) {   // This method is going to retrieve the child nodes
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(childNodes.getLength());

    for (int i = 1; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node cNode = childNodes.item(i);

        System.out.println(cNode.getNodeName());
        /**
         * This will get the attribute of the node 
         */
        if (cNode.hasAttributes()) {

            NamedNodeMap nodeMap = cNode.getAttributes();
            for (int f = 0; f < nodeMap.getLength(); f++) {
                System.out.println("Att " + nodeMap.item(f).getNodeName()
                        + " " + nodeMap.item(f).getNodeValue());
            }
        }

        if (cNode.hasChildNodes()) {

            // For getting the value if node has more than 2 or atleast two childs

            if (cNode.getChildNodes().getLength() >= 2) {

                getChildNode(cNode.getChildNodes());
            }

            // For getting the node has no childs and it contains text node value

            else if (cNode.getNodeType() == cNode.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element ele = (Element) cNode;
                System.out.println("\t" + ele.getTextContent());

            }
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Could you please let me know if I have to parse only below two attribute form the xml and assign into a variable:


<attr name="sn"><value>kevin</value></attr>
  <attr name="givenName"><value>stifford</value></attr>

Comment: can you help in this  its very important for me from the two values have to generate dynamic username and password

Comment: its working fine when i am running on my machine          <class><attr name="sn"><value>kevin</value></attr> <attr name="givenName"><value>stifford</value></attr>                </class>   here "class" is the root tag

Comment: i want to parse only these two values.i dont want to parse rest of the values

Comment: In that case you can take the node by the nodeName and then later you can retrieve its child element and get the attribute value

Comment: ok thanks you i need one help from you.i have a written a program that serach entries in eDirectory but i want to generate UID based upon the firstname and sn .and if the uid is present it must incriment to 1.ex:sacbad is present it must incriment to sacbad1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16564672/assign-unique-uid-value-dynamically-based-upon-3-character-of-sn-and-givenname pls check this link i mentioned the programme

Comment: hi buddy i can parse the xml and get UID

Comment: how to call a class getunique id

Answer (score 0):

One way to go would be to do it manually, by evaluating the strings.
Another would be to use one of all the available Java XML libraries... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Processing

Comment: i hv tried but this xml is in different format so while parsing it is not accepting pls help

Comment: it is showing batch request but cant able to read all the values.because it is a dsml form of xml which the attribute must match the edirectory and store value in that'

Comment: In android you can parse xml in two ways. DOM or SAX, just google it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is specific for a parser type. If you are going to use DOM parser, probably [this](http://java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/DOM-Attribute.htm) will be helpful. These are [examples](http://java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/SAX.htm) for the SAX parser.